# What are the restrictions of node ID in GraphViz?

Tags: graphviz

For example, here are the results if I use the IDs `1a` and `2.2.2` for nodes:

[image]

[image]

How does this work? What are other restrictions on the node name? I look at [Attributes | Graphviz](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html) but it doesn't explain.

Can I do something like this?

```
0 -> {1a, 1b, 2, 3} 
1b -> 2
1b.1 -> {1b.1.1}
1b.1.1 -> {1b.1.1.1, 1b.1.1.3}
1b.2 -> {1b.2.1, 1b.2.2}
1b.2.2 -> {1b.2.2.1, 1b.2.2.2}
2 -> 2.1
3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [DOT language documentation](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html), you should use quotes for the node ID:

> An ID is one of the following:
>
> - Any string of alphabetic ([a-zA-Z\200-\377]) characters, underscores
>   ('_') or digits([0-9]), not beginning with a digit;
> - a numeral [-]?(.[0-9]⁺ | [0-9]⁺(.[0-9]*)? );
> - any double-quoted string ("...") possibly containing escaped quotes (")¹;
> - an HTML string (<...>).

An ID is just a string; the lack of quote characters in the first two
forms is just for simplicity. There is no semantic difference between
abc_2 and "abc_2", or between 2.34 and "2.34".

So, for your example, it will work as follows:

```
digraph example {
  "0" -> {"1a", "1b", "2", "3"} 
  "1b" -> "2"
  "1b.1" -> {"1b.1.1"}
  "1b.1.1" -> {"1b.1.1.1", "1b.1.1.3"}
  "1b.2" -> {"1b.2.1", "1b.2.2"}
  "1b.2.2" -> {"1b.2.2.1", "1b.2.2.2"}
  "2" -> "2.1"
  "3"
}
```